# How to solve "cgroup mountpoint not found for memory" with docker.io

Tags: docker

How do I solve `cgroup mountpoint not found for memory` while using docker.io ?

I have ubuntu-14.04 intalled, kernel version 3.13.0-20-generic. Docker version is 0.8.1.

Answer (score 5):

Solution: restart the computer.

The underlying problem appears to be with how cgroups are handled by the kernel. It seems that a kernel restart is needed for `cgmanager` to be applied.

Comment: P.S. I'm answering according to stackoverflow guidelines: 
"It’s OK to Ask and Answer Your Own Questions"  http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/